# Inserting Unicode character using asp.net mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a database field with nVarchar(30). I am using asp.net MVC. When i insert the record in Unicode, i get ?????.

Any one can tell me how can i convert a string to unicode and insert into database.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: How are you inserting the record? Please post your code.

Comment: I am using strongly typed view to pass data and inserting it using the controller

Comment: How? Concatenating SQL? Parameterized query? ORM? Something else?

Comment: I am using ADO.NET entity data model, So I simply fill the model and call the db.Villages.add(village); and db.saveChanges();

Comment: The record inserts but after displaying I get (????) but i want to insert some Persian characters. (نیست)

Comment: Where are you displaying? How are you displaying? What do you see in the database when you use management studio?

Comment: I see the ?????? instead of the Persian text in management studio and on my webpage. I see all the other english characters correctly

Comment: When debugging through, do you see the correct characters passed into the MVC action?

Comment: Yes. There is no problem I see while debugging through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your database collation to Latin1_General_BIN2.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175835.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure:

1. You Use `N'` at the start of string literals containing such strings, e.g. `N'enović'`
2. If you want to query and ignore accents, then you can add a COLLATE clause to your select. E.g.:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM Account 
   WHERE Name = 'enovic' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
   ```